# Scraping an interactive table with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm attempting to scrape the second table shown at the URL below, and I'm running into issues which may be related to the interactive nature of the table.

div_stats_standard appears to refer to the table of interest.

The code runs with no errors but returns an empty list.

```
url <- 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats'

data <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[(@id = "div_stats_standard")]') %>%
  html_table()
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Xpath is doing it the hard way--try selecting with a "table" css selector instead. Also note--the TOS are pretty clear about the fact that they would prefer that you not do this this way.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the table.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats"

page <- read_html(url)
nodes <- html_nodes(page, "table") # you can use Selectorgadget to identify the node
table <- html_table(nodes[[1]]) # each element of the nodes list is one table that can be extracted
head(table)
```

Result:

```
head(table)
                   Playing Time Playing Time Playing Time Performance Performance
1       Squad # Pl           MP       Starts          Min         Gls         Ast
2     Arsenal   26           27          297        2,430          39          26
3 Aston Villa   28           27          297        2,430          33          27
4 Bournemouth   25           28          308        2,520          27          17
5    Brighton   23           28          308        2,520          28          19
6     Burnley   21           28          308        2,520          32          23
  Performance Performance Performance Performance Per 90 Minutes Per 90 Minutes
1          PK       PKatt        CrdY        CrdR            Gls            Ast
2           2           2          64           3           1.44           0.96
3           1           3          54           1           1.22           1.00
4           1           1          60           3           0.96           0.61
5           1           1          44           2           1.00           0.68
6           2           2          53           0           1.14           0.82
  Per 90 Minutes Per 90 Minutes Per 90 Minutes Expected Expected Expected Per 90 Minutes
1            G+A           G-PK         G+A-PK       xG     npxG       xA             xG
2           2.41           1.37           2.33     35.0     33.5     21.3           1.30
3           2.22           1.19           2.19     30.6     28.2     22.0           1.13
4           1.57           0.93           1.54     31.2     30.5     20.8           1.12
5           1.68           0.96           1.64     33.8     33.1     22.4           1.21
6           1.96           1.07           1.89     30.9     29.4     18.9           1.10
  Per 90 Minutes Per 90 Minutes Per 90 Minutes Per 90 Minutes
1             xA          xG+xA           npxG        npxG+xA
2           0.79           2.09           1.24           2.03
3           0.81           1.95           1.04           1.86
4           0.74           1.86           1.09           1.83
5           0.80           2.01           1.18           1.98
6           0.68           1.78           1.05           1.73
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This works for table 1, but it isn't clear which node is marking table 2 on the page.